# Data not changing when store state changes

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

i have some data in a component that is set to the stores state like so:

```
data() {
    return {
      days: [],
      selectedDate: this.selectedDateComputed,
      dayJs: this.$store.state.dayJS,
    };
  },
```

but when the stores state gets updated
it doesnt update the dayJs state in the component.

I tried making it a computed property, with the selectedDate data like so:

```
selectedDateComputed() {
    return this.$store.state.dayJS;
  },
```

but selectedDate does not update either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect changes to the store's state, you need to use the `mapState` helper function provided by Vuex. Take a look at [the docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper).

```js
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["dayJS"])
  }
}
```